# Need to have one string from Looped Chars JS

Tags: javascript

need to get the output as 1 string instead of looped string
the output I got each letter on its own
need to have the second output which is one word

Thanks in advance:D

```
let start = 0;
let swappedName = "elZerO";

for (let i = start; i<swappedName.length; i++){
    if (swappedName[i] == swappedName[i].toUpperCase()) {
        console.log(swappedName[i].toLowerCase());
    }else {
        console.log(swappedName[i].toUpperCase());
    }
}

//Output
E
L
z
E
R
o

// Need to be 
"ELzERo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string = string0+string1` , or keep adding values to an array, then join the array with `array.join()`

[MasteringJs has a great guide on ways to merge characters and strings.](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat)

```js
let start = 0;
let swappedName = "elZerO";
var outputString="";
var outputStringArray=[];
var newChar="";
for (let i = start; i<swappedName.length; i++){
    if (swappedName[i] == swappedName[i].toUpperCase()) {
      newChar = swappedName[i].toLowerCase();
    }else {
        newChar=swappedName[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    outputStringArray.push(newChar);
    outputString+=newChar;
}
console.log("[Output using string1 + string 2] is "+outputString); // Another example of concating string

console.log("[Output using array.join] is "+outputStringArray.join("")); // Another example of concating string
// Need to be 
"ELzERo"
```